# L'expression « mon médecin m'a arrêtée » est-elle correcte ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je suis de culture belge, ma copine de culture française.

Plus tôt ce matin, elle m'écrit « mon médecin m'a arrêtée deux jours », voulant me dire, vu son état de santé, que son médecin lui a fourni une attestation médicale d'interruption de travail.

J'ai travaillé à de nombreuses reprises avec des Français dans le passé et au fil des maladies, je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression auparavant.

Est-ce une expression correcte et utilisée fréquemment en France ? Je n'ai pas trouvé de traces de celle-ci dans différents dictionnaires en ligne ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/arr%C3%AAter), [Trésor de la Langue Française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/)).

Comment: Je confirme également en tant que belge que je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression

Comment: Le language parlé n'est pas toujours dans les dicos. Parfois, cela se dit comme ça et seulement les locuteurs du pays ou de la communauté linguistique vont pouvoir infirmer/confirmer. Il y a des centaines de tournures qui s'entendent malgré les puristes ou toute sorte de purisme...

Comment: Whether or not it's short for something more formal/grammatical, it seems to me like it could be used as a quick and simple (and rather clever, imo), discussion/debate-stifling way of shifting attention on/blame for an absence away from oneself (and even away from the actual seriousness, or not, of one’s condition) to the doctor and his/her professional opinion, similar to Flip Wilson’s “[I really hated to take off all last week, but] **The devil/[doctor] made me do it!**”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pour ma part, je suis Français, c'est une expression que j'ai entendue très souvent, pour ne pas dire systématiquement, lorsqu'une personne est en arrêt de travail pour cause de maladie.

Comment: [Un médecin l'arrête trois jours](http://www.lamontagne.fr/thiers/2009/02/18/l-ancien-ouvrier-turc-a-tue-son-medecin_131871.html). [j'ai été arrêté trois jours. J'étais tellement fatigué que le médecin m'a donné ces quelques jours](https://books.google.fr/books?id=DPUXCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=m%C3%A9decin+%22arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9+trois+jours%22&source=bl&ots=xfkHd1ikXL&sig=PpEzGZi8mlQWS0WvAKGrSEXp2wg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW6qOM-NbWAhXOh7QKHYXRAJYQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=m%C3%A9decin%20%22arr%C3%AAt%C3%A9%20trois%20jours%22&f=false).   Beaucoup d'autres exemples à trouver...

Comment: Merci, ceci répond à l'une des deux questions, à savoir l'usage. Mais l'expression en elle-même est-elle correcte ? Est-elle répertoriée dans des ouvrages de référence, comme des dictionnaires ?

Comment: Dans le genre bien dit, c'est plutôt, "m'a donné un arrêt de travail". Mais dans le genre populaire, on dit bien: il m'a arrête....

Comment: @Lambie Je dirais "prescrit" plutôt que "donné".

Comment: @mouviciel On entend "donner", "fait", "prescrit" etc.

Comment: @Lambie -  Pardon, j'avais compris "genre bien dit" dans le sens "terminologie officielle", par exemple sur le site [Ameli](https://www.ameli.fr/assure/droits-demarches/maladie-accident-hospitalisation/arret-travail-maladie/arret-travail-maladie) de la sécurité sociale.

Comment: @mouviciel Le bien dire et le dire formel ou officiel, ce n'est pas pareil. Le langage parlé n'est pas toujours officiel. Moi, justement, je ne faisais pas allusion à la terminologie officielle. :)

Answer (score 6):

Le médecin remplit un formulaire officiel (cerfa n°XXX) qui se nomme "avis d’arrêt de travail" avec un certificat d'arrêt de travail inclus.

L'expression correcte serait plutôt "le médecin m'a prescrit un arrêt de travail". Mais dans l'usage courant, cette expression "le médecin m'a arrêté" s'est banalisée. Cf le dictionnaire Larousse, arrêter :

> Familier. Autoriser quelqu'un à suspendre son travail pour raison de santé : Le médecin l'a arrêté 8 jours.

Answer (score 1):

La phrase complète (c'est-à-dire approuvée par l'Académie Française) serait probablement : "Le médecin m'a mis(e)/placé(e) en arrêt maladie pour xxx jours".

À partir de cette phrase, beaucoup de variations sont possibles, y compris "le médecin m'a arrêté(e) 2 jours", qui doit être considéré comme une réécriture de la phrase de départ.